# Where to store images the user has selected from their gallery?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So one of the functionalities of the ***prototype app*** I'm making allows the user to create a recipe and add a thumbnail and video to it. Once a user has selected an image from their gallery for the thumbnail and a video, how and where should I store it so that it can be retrieved whenever the recipe is viewed again?

Comment: You should leave it where it was and only store uri or path to that file.

Comment: @blackapps Ahh ok, how could I do that? Are there any tutorials you suggest? (Sorry, this is just really new to me)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code to store an image in the DCIM/ directory

```
    @Throws(IOException::class)
    private fun saveImage(bitmap: Bitmap, name: String) {
        val saved: Boolean
        val fos: OutputStream?
        fos = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            val resolver: ContentResolver = requireActivity().contentResolver
            val contentValues = ContentValues()
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, name)
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/png")
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, "DCIM/$IMAGE_DIRECTORY")
            val imageUri =
                resolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues)
            resolver.openOutputStream(imageUri!!)
        } else {
            val imagesDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM
            ).toString() + File.separator + IMAGE_DIRECTORY
            val file = File(imagesDir)
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.mkdir()
            }
            val image = File(imagesDir, "$name.png")
            FileOutputStream(image)
        }
        saved = bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos)
        fos!!.flush()
        fos.close()
    }
```

Then get all the images as a list of URI like so

```
private fun getAllImages(): List<Uri>
    {
        val allImages = mutableListOf<Uri>()

        val imageProjection = arrayOf(
            MediaStore.Images.Media._ID
        )

        val imageSortOrder = "${MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED} DESC"

        val cursor = activity?.contentResolver?.query(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            imageProjection,
            null,
            null,
            imageSortOrder
        )

        cursor.use {

            if (cursor != null)
            {
                val idColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID)
                while (cursor.moveToNext())
                {
                    allImages.add(
                        ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                            cursor.getLong(idColumn)
                        )
                    )
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Log.d("AddViewModel", "Cursor is null!")
            }
        }
        return allImages
    }
```

Then query it to find the required image

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this out

Comment: Sure. Let me know if you face any issues and accept the answer if it works.Welcome to stackOverflow, :)

Comment: If possible, would you be able to provide a java version of this? I'm not familiar with kotlin...